# Jquery change opacity of item if not chosen in select

Tags: jquery

I have a select as follows:

```
<select>
 <option value="cat-1">cat 1</option>
 <option value="cat-2">cat 2</option>
 <option value="cat-3">cat 3</option>
</select>
```

I have divs with content:

```
<div class="cat-1">
<div class="cat-2">
<div class="cat-3">
```

I want to change the opacity of the items which weren't selected, so if the select is changed to cat-1, then divs cat-2 and cat-3 get their opacity changed

I have the following JS which changes the opacity of the selected div, I just need to amend it to do the opposite

```
$("#shoe-men,#shoe-women,#shoe-kids").on('change', function() {
 var $Select = $(this).val();
 $('.'+$Select).css('opacity','1');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You might just add a shared class to all those divs, blanket add opacity to all of them except the one that matches the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have given `<select>` an ID in your origin code so you can use:

```
$('#cat-sel').change(function(){
    $('#cat-sel option').each(function() {
        if($(this).prop('selected')){
            $('.'+$(this).val()).css('opacity',1);
        }else{
            $('.'+$(this).val()).css('opacity',0.2);
        }
    })
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Frederick888/7zh11gqc/

Answer (score 3):

Give them all a class that's the same, then use `.not()`

```
<div class="cat cat-1">
<div class="cat cat-2">
<div class="cat cat-3">
```

then

```
$("#shoe-men,#shoe-women,#shoe-kids").on('change', function() {
    var $Select = $(this).val();
    var $cat = $('.'+$Select)
    $cat.css('opacity','1');

    // now add:
    $(".cat").not($cat).css('opacity', '0.5');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set all of the divs opacity to desired amount (.4 for example), then just set the selected opacity to 1:

```
   $("#shoe-men,#shoe-women,#shoe-kids").on('change', function() {
      var $Select = $(this).val();
      $('.cat-1, .cat-2, .cat-3').css('opacity', '.4');
      $('.'+$Select).css('opacity','1');
   });
```

Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/o6cau211/1/